# Is it possible to wrap an if statement around javascript `.click` function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running into trouble whenever I wrap javascript `.click` function into an if statement like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = "something";
    if (test == "something"){
        $("#" + test).click(function(){
            do_something();
        });
    }
});
```

What happens is that the `.click` doesn't do the binding as compared to not wrapping around an if statment. Is this an expected behavior?

Edit: element `"#" + test` has a possibility of not existing, that's why I have the outer condition

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What behavior?

Comment: Is `test` defined somewhere?

Comment: Okay after your edit...Well if the code does not go into the if, than it will not be bound. Are you expecting the quick to be bound when the if is not true? When the variable `test` is changed, it does not rerun the if statement, once it executes it is done.

Comment: So, you want to bind the event if and only if `test == "something"` when the page initially loads?  Are you sure you didn't mean to put the `if` statement *inside* the event?  P.S. What is `test` supposed to be?  You're doing `$(test)`, so I'm curious.

Comment: If you do `$('#test')` and the element does not exist, then you'll be returned an *empty* jQuery object.  You can call `.click()` on it, but it just won't do anything.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking so I'm voting to close this. Please rewrite the question to clearly indicate exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish (consider explaining the *why* rather than asking about the *how*).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the condition inside the click function.

```
    $(test).click(function(){
        if (test == "something"){
            do_something();
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**:  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvtmcy8o/)

Comment: the reason I don't want to do that is because test have a possibility of not existing, if so the binding will cause error

Comment: I've added a fiddle to my answer to demo.

Comment: @user445670 you may not want to, but you kind of have to. It's the only way it will work. If the condition is not inside the click it's not being tested when the click happens but rather only once at document load. That's unlikely to be what you want.